# Try/Except statement for widget entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

```
try:
      float(self.entry_weight.get()) and int(self.entry_height.get())
      self.get_bears()
except:
      messagebox.showinfo("Number Error","Your weight and height must be a number!")
```

Hello,
This try/except statement doesn't seem to be working, when I input numbers into the entry boxes, and click the associated button, I only get the message box saying that my inputs are not numbers. 
I have used print statements to make sure I am testing the right entry boxes and i am.  When i test the type i get back  as expected but surely if these string inputs are numbers, the try except statement should work. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: The `and` keyword doesn't do what you think it does. Also another tip: Never catch *all* possible Exceptions, just the ones you expect, so you can handle them properly

Comment: @user8408080 - ...but works unless weight is zero.

Comment: Yes, `0` is casted to `False` by Python, but you've got to agree, that this check should not be done like that

Comment: `and` short-circuits as soon as a False is detected. If weight is zero, the test is never made. If your goal is to test whether these two values can be converted, do it on separate lines with no "and"

Comment: @user8408080 - Yes, I agree. Its just that its not the explanation for the problem.

Comment: You guys are mentioning the weight? What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your try/except block covers too much territory. In addition to problems with input, it catches everything that could go wrong with `get_bears`. Additionally, `and` short-circuits so the second check is never made if weight is 0. You can use two try/except blocks to cover everything

```
try:
    # validate input
    float(self.entry_weight.get())
    int(self.entry_height.get())
except ValueError:
      messagebox.showinfo("Number Error","Your weight and height must be a number!")
      return
try:
    self.get_bears()
except:
    messagebox.showinfo("Unhandled Error","Unknown error in program")
    # log it somewhere
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    # likely want to exit() because program is highly busted
```

Comment: thank you, i was able to find the problem in self.get_bears()